# Save images from attached file at couchdb

Tags: python-3.x, couchdb

I have an image saved as an attached file in my CouchDB, I need to get the image with a GET Request and save the image locally but can't find a way around it. When I uploaded the image file i got this JSON in return

{
  "_id": "95a51bbb8cfbb2abd07c6d14441f662a",
  "_rev": "3-15b7700d2df8fd896065c77a0c66ff11",
  "_attachments": {
    "chris.jpg": {
      "content_type": "image/jpeg",
      "revpos": 2,
      "digest": "md5-gTXsroZpTQ3qRrIsTKGoxw==",
      "length": 53644,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
}

I do know that if I wanted to display the image in a HTML page I would use the blob format, but can't figure out how to use it for saving in a local directory; please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/{db}/{docid}/{attachment}` endpoint as documented [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/document/attachments.html). It will return just the attachment you want.

If you're using a CouchDB client library, it probably makes this easier for you.

Answer (score -1):

Well in case someone faces this issue again, what I finally did was:

```
r= requests.get(full_url)
superData = r.json()
```

to get the JSON from couchdb, next:

```
for key in superData["_attachments"]:
    nuevaURL = full_url + '/' +key
    response = requests.get(nuevaURL, stream=True)
```

to get the path to the image and finally to save it locally:

```
with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient approach, and much more work than just fetching the attachment.